# How to disable VPCLMULQDQ instruction set in build server (DPDK 21.11)

Tags: gcc, dpdk

I am very new to DPDK and related applications.

I have a build server (on which I am compiling my binaries) which is newer than the target server (on which I am running the binaries).

The build server supports VPCLMULQDQ but the target server does not, as seen in the lscpu output

This is resulting in an error when running the associated binary,

```
ERROR: This system does not support "VPCLMULQDQ".
Please check that RTE_MACHINE is set correctly.
EAL: FATAL: unsupported cpu type.
EAL: unsupported cpu type.
rte_eal_init failed
 RTE EAL INIT UNSUCCESSFUL
```

I have tried setting the platform to generic by running `meson configure -Dplatform=native` as well as changing it in meson_options.txt, but I am still facing the same issue.

Also, using chatGPT's help I tried using `-Dmachine_args='-mnovpclmulqdq'` but I have not found any supporting document related to the same elsewhere.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Do you have any updates? Did you manage to fix it?